# How to draw triangle shape and add it into relative or linear layout android

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, ondraw

I am developing small android application in  which I m using my custom linear layout class. In that class i tried to draw one small triangle and tried to include it in to my linear layout but I m not able to do that. I tried it in following ways ...

```
@SuppressLint("DrawAllocation")
public class SimpleLin extends LinearLayout {
    public String TAG = "CustomviewActivity";   
    LinearLayout parentLayout;

    public SimpleLin(Context context) 
    {
        super(context);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if(inflater != null){   
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main2, this);d.lin_llt);
        parentLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bcd);

      }

    }

    public SimpleLin(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

        super( context, attrs );

        context1= context;
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        super.onDraw(canvas);
        Log.i("############################", "inside ondraw");
        Paint p = new Paint();
        p.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        p.setColor(Color.RED);
        Point point = new Point();
        point.x = 80;
        point.y = 80;
        Path path = getEquilateralTriangle(point, 70, Direction.SOUTH);
        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(500, 500, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        canvas.drawPath(path, p);
    }
    public static Path getEquilateralTriangle(Point p1, int width, Direction direction) {
        Point p2 = null, p3 = null;

        if (direction == Direction.NORTH) {
            p2 = new Point(p1.x + width, p1.y);
            p3 = new Point(p1.x + (width / 2), p1.y - width);
        }
        else if (direction == Direction.SOUTH) {
            p2 = new Point(p1.x + width,p1.y);
            p3 = new Point(p1.x + (width / 2), p1.y + width);
        }
        else if (direction == Direction.EAST) {
            p2 = new Point(p1.x, p1.y + width);
            p3 = new Point(p1.x - width, p1.y + (width / 2));
        }
        else if (direction == Direction.WEST) {
            p2 = new Point(p1.x, p1.y + width);
            p3 = new Point(p1.x + width, p1.y + (width / 2));
        }

        Path path = new Path();
        path.moveTo(p1.x, p1.y);
        path.lineTo(p2.x, p2.y);
        path.lineTo(p3.x, p3.y);

        return path;
    }
    public enum Direction 
    {
        NORTH, SOUTH, EAST, WEST;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void initialiseImages()
    {
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

I am calling `initialiseImages` method from my activity where i wanted to use this custom layout. So problem is that It not calling my on draw method when i use invalidate(). That's why it not drawing my triangle. and I am also confuse how to include that triangle into my `parentlayout`..
Is there wrong in my code..
How to draw such shapes in android...
Need help...
Thank you...

Comment: why do you need the inflater in the constructor ? you said, you are just trying to draw a triangle right ?

Comment: yeah becoz i wanted to add that triangle into that linear layout as well.. Any idea.. Need help.

Comment: you don't need to, you are extending a Linear Layout then you are inflating one again, go through the dev links for custom view, in the meanwhile i'll get you a sample code

Comment: yeah sure. thank you for your good support

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Code for Custom Linear Layout (I modified your code so its easier for you to understand)

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

/**
 * @author Atrix1987
 * 
 */
public class CustomView extends LinearLayout {

    /**
     * @param context
     */
    public CustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        commonConstructor(context);
    }

    /**
     * @param context
     * @param attrs
     */
    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        commonConstructor(context);
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    Paint trianglePaint;
    /**
     * 
     */
    Path trianglePath;

    /**
     * @param context
     */
    private void commonConstructor(Context context) {
        trianglePaint = new Paint();
        trianglePaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        trianglePaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        Point point = new Point();
        point.x = 80;
        point.y = 80;
        trianglePath = getEquilateralTriangle(point, 70, Direction.SOUTH);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        Log.i("Sample", "inside ondraw");
        //avoid creating objects in onDraw
        canvas.drawPath(trianglePath, trianglePaint);
    }

    private Path getEquilateralTriangle(Point p1, int width, Direction direction) {
        Log.i("Sample", "inside getEqui");
        Point p2 = null, p3 = null;

        if (direction == Direction.NORTH) {
            p2 = new Point(p1.x + width, p1.y);
            p3 = new Point(p1.x + (width / 2), p1.y - width);
        } else if (direction == Direction.SOUTH) {
            p2 = new Point(p1.x + width, p1.y);
            p3 = new Point(p1.x + (width / 2), p1.y + width);
        } else if (direction == Direction.EAST) {
            p2 = new Point(p1.x, p1.y + width);
            p3 = new Point(p1.x - width, p1.y + (width / 2));
        } else if (direction == Direction.WEST) {
            p2 = new Point(p1.x, p1.y + width);
            p3 = new Point(p1.x + width, p1.y + (width / 2));
        }

        Path path = new Path();
        path.moveTo(p1.x, p1.y);
        path.lineTo(p2.x, p2.y);
        path.lineTo(p3.x, p3.y);

        return path;
    }

    public enum Direction {
        NORTH, SOUTH, EAST, WEST;
    }

}
```

The code for the activity (For simplicity and as a shortcut i did this, you can also specify it in the xml and just setContentView):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;

/**
 * @author Atrix1987
 *
 */
public class SampleActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        CustomView cv = new CustomView(getApplicationContext());
        cv.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        setContentView(cv, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    }

}
```

Do explore the developer site [links](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html) for custom views, for more insight.

Hope this helps.

PFB the screenshot[image: The screenshot from the sample i ran]

Answer (score 4):

If you are wanting a drawable you can use, try this http://looksok.wordpress.com/2013/08/24/android-triangle-arrow-defined-as-an-xml-shape/ sadly I can't claim credit